# Perl set timeout within thread fails: 'Alarm clock'

Tags: multithreading, perl, timeout, pthreads

I have a threaded application and would like to set timeouts for the threads. [Peldoc for alarm](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/alarm.html) suggests to use a `eval`-`die` pair and catch the `ALRM` signal. However, this fails with threads producing the error `Alarm clock`:

```
use strict; use warnings;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
require threads;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
require threads::shared;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

my $t = threads->create( sub {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        

    eval {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "alarm\n" };                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        alarm 2;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        main();                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        alarm 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    };                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    if ($@){                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        die $@ unless $@ eq "alarm\n";                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        print "timed out\n";                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                 }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    );                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

my @r = $t->join;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
print "done\n";                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

sub main {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    sleep 3;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
}
```

[This post](http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=499875) suggests that `alarm` is called without signal handler in the `threads` library. [Another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3603518/perl-threads-and-unsafe-signals) is about this problem and answers suggest to use `fork` and `waitpid`, but I would really like to use `threads`. [Another post](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=949069) claims to come up with a solution, but this still gives the `Alarm clock` error for me. I tried to catch `Alarm clock` in the `if ($@)`, but no success. Any idea how I could make this work?

Comment: I see. So would there be a workaround for this? My whole application really relies on `threads`

Comment: Yes, use some mechanism other than kill signals. Something like semaphores or queues.

Answer (score 3):

The whole idea of using alarm in threads is problematic.

1. Signals are sent to processes, not threads.
2. What if two threads want to use `alarm`?

You'll have to implement your own system. The following is an attempt at a general solution:

```
package Threads::Alarm;

use strict;
use warnings;

use threads;
use threads::shared;

use Exporter qw( import );


our @EXPORT_OK = qw( alarm thread_alarm );


# A list of "$time:$tid" strings sorted by ascending time.
my @alarms :shared;

sub thread_alarm {
   my ($wait) = @_;

   my $tid  = threads->tid();

   lock @alarms;

   # Cancel existing alarm for this thread, if any.
   for my $i (0..$#alarms) {
      if ((split(/:/, $alarms[$i]))[1] == $tid) {
         splice(@alarms, $i, 1);
         last;
      }
   }

   # Create an alarm
   if ($wait) {
      my $when = time() + $wait;

      # A binary search would be better.
      my $i;
      for ($i=0; $i<@alarms; ++$i) {
         last if $when < (split(/:/, $alarms[$i]))[0];
      }

      splice(@alarms, $i, 0, "$when:$tid");
   }

   # Notify others of change to @alarms.
   cond_broadcast(@alarms);
}


{
   no warnings 'once';
   *alarm = \&thread_alarm;
}


threads->create(sub {
   while (1) {
      my $thread;

      {
         lock @alarms;

         while (1) {
            # Wait for an alarm request to come in.
            cond_wait(@alarms) while !@alarms;

            # Grab the soonest alarm.
            my ($when, $tid) = split(/:/, $alarms[0]);
            # Check if the thread still exists.
            my $thread = threads->object($tid)
               or last;

            # Wait for the @alarms to change or for the alarm time.    
            last if !cond_timedwait(@alarms, $when);
         }

         # Before releasing the lock, remove the alarm we're about to raise.
         shift(@alarms);

         # Notify others of change to @alarms.
         # Doesn't actually do anything at this time.
         cond_broadcast(@alarms);
      }

      $thread->kill('ALRM') if $thread;
   }
})->detach();


1;
```

Completely untested. Well, I made sure it compiles, but that's it.

Note that `threads->kill` doesn't send a real signal (since those are sent to processes, not threads), so the OS won't interrupt any operation (e.g. `sleep`, `wait`). Simple solution: Send a real signal to a handler that does nothing right after calling `threads->kill`. Maybe I should have written a solution that was based around the actual `SIGALRM`.